# UTF-8 encoding characters not working with Spring mvc & lowagie itext

Tags: spring, pdf, utf-8, itext

In my spring's controller method , i am using lowagie api (2.1.7) to generate pdf. Expecting output after pdf generation is "Swapnil Shirke 병준 주 Тимофій Чепурний" instead of "Swapnil Shirke". special characters are not display in pdf.

UTF-8 encoding characters not working

```
String graphInfo =
 "<div style="" align="left">on: 09/14/2017<br/>Report generated by: Swapnil Shirke Тимофій Чепурний 병준 주<br/><br/>cd: kkEBM<br/>bbdre: EjydeBM<br/></div><br/><div align="center" style="font-size:14px;">test</div><br/> ";

String tblHtml="<tr><td>Swapnil Shirke Тимофій Чепурний 병준 주</td></tr>";

response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
Document document = new Document();
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A3);
pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
document.open();
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(graphInfo.toString()));
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader("<br/>" + tblHtml));
document.close();
```

Comment: I am Lowagie. You are using an API that I once wrote, and that [should no longer be used](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). One of the (many) reasons why you should no longer use it, is its age. iText 2.1.7 dates from 2009. As you can read in the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml), the `HTMLWorker` class is obsolete. It can't handle more than one font in a `<td>` (which is what you need). No one will fix this because that problem is adequately fixed in [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML).

Comment: In short: you need to upgrade to iText 7 + pdfHTML. *On a personal note:* adults get embarrassed when their parents publish pictures dating from when they were a teenager. For similar reasons, your use of iText 2.1.7 embarrasses me. Your use of that old version reveals errors that have long been fixed. The library has grown and it has become more mature, just like teenagers become wiser when they grow up. Ask yourself: what would your customer want? Would he prefer a puberal or a mature solution?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I think they would prefer a free solution:) But you did a great job! Thank you.