# Show footer only on last page

Tags: itext, flying-saucer

I'm using flyingsaucer 9.1.1 with itext 2.17 to generate pdf files.

How can I show a footer (could be a div, a table or an img element) only on the last page but not on the other ones?

Comment: iText 2.1.7 is an API that I once wrote, and [that should no longer be used](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). One of the (many) reasons why you should no longer use it, is its age. iText 2.1.7 dates from 2009. You are also using Flying Saucer. That's an old third party library written on top of that old iText version. You should consider using [iText 7 + pdfHTML](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml). Browsing the tutorial, you'll notice that there much more support for CSS in [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML).

Comment: As for your question, you can use an `IEventHandler` to create a footer that shows custom behavior, should you decide to do the right thing and upgrade to iText 7. The [tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml) has an example of how custom headers or footers can be created. You might also want to read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238645/utf-8-encoding-characters-not-working-with-spring-mvc-lowagie-itext#comment79441200_46238645)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, CSS defines the [`page:first`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#first-pseudo) pseudo element, but doesn't define `page:last`.

You still have the possibility to take advantage of a [bug](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/issues/146) of flying-saucer, that makes the footer only appear after it is declared. So if you put the footer `div` at the end of the HTML, it will only appear on the last page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
    .newpage{page-break-before:always}

    @page{@bottom-center {content: element(footer)}}
    #footer {position: running(footer);}    
}
 </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>Page 1 content</div>
        <div class="newpage">Page 2 content</div>
        <div class="newpage">Page 3 content</div>
        <div id="footer">Footer on last page</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It also works if you want a footer on each page, with a different content for the last page. You just have to define the footer `div` twice in the HTML.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
    .newpage{page-break-before:always}

    @page{
      @bottom-center {content: element(footer)}}
      #footer {position: running(footer);}    
    }
 </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="footer">Footer for all pages except last</div>
        <div>Page 1 content</div>
        <div class="newpage">Page 2 content</div>
        <div class="newpage">Page 3 content</div>
        <div id="footer">Footer on last page</div>
    </body>
</html>
```